# localView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(false) not working

Tags: android, surfaceview

i'm new to android. I have 2 surface view (localView and remoteView) by default i'm putting localView on top of remoteView using "localView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);".till now everything is working fine, but i have button (swap) which swap the two views position such a way that remoteView should come on top of localView. i have made "localView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(false);" and "remoteView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)" in onClickListner but its not working.

remoteView is not appearing on top of localView. I can see that it is behind the localView.

here is my code:

```
        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/remote_surface"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
            />
        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/local_surface"
            android:layout_height="180px"
            android:layout_width="180px"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as described in theAPI: `Note that this must be set before the surface view's containing window is attached to the window manager. ` so I guess it doesn´t work dynamically, only before the views are attached to the window. I think here you have to modify your code a little bit....

Answer (score 1):

As @Opiatefuchs noted in a comment, [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay(boolean)) say you can't change the SurfaceView Surface's Z-order after the Surface has been set up.

You have a couple of options.  One possibility is to change how the Surfaces are drawn.  If, for example, both were drawn with OpenGL ES, you would simply swap the EGL context associated with the renderers.  (Or, for that matter, draw all content on a single SurfaceView, and reverse the order or depth at which content is rendered.)

For other data sources, e.g. MediaPlayer, it may not be quite so straightforward or seamless.  It might be worth replacing SurfaceView with [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html), as that can be ordered through the layout like any other View.  This will likely be less efficient than SurfaceView though due to the extra copy.